# FTP not getting connected from outside LAN

Tags: networking, firewall, ftp, port-forwarding, filezilla

I am ussing FileZilla server, I created a shared folder and able to connect and transfer files within LAN. But when I try to connect from outside LAN, i am getting following error:

> Connect socket #1452to 192. XX. XX.X% port 56635...
> 425 Can't open data connection.
> STOR command failed
> Error loading directory...

I don't have much knowledge on ports in server settings custom port range selected and given port range 50000-51000. Firewall inbound rule all ports are selected [firewall rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFpQ.png), my router port forwarding interface is [port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAlR8.png) .

Error images:

- [filezilla client error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p74zB.png)
- [core ftp client error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7pvG.png).

Please help me.